# How to set nosetests to only log errors?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have a hundred or so unit tests I'm running with nose. When I change something in my models obviously I get fails, with some errors mixed in. Is there an easy way to tell nose to only log the errors? Then I don't have to go through pages of fails to look for one error log.

Comment: Have you tried using any of the `--logging-*` flags that nose provides?

Comment: Yes something like that, but I can't find anything in the docs that tells me how to get what I need.

Comment: Does `--logging-clear-handlers` help?

Comment: No sorry, still shows the mix of errors and fails.

Comment: Have you tried with `--logging-level=ERROR`?

Comment: I guess that helps a bit. It still shows the Error and Fails messages, but not the whole dump for Fails, so the response is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

nose provides tools for testing exceptions (like unittest does). Try this example (and read about the other tools at Nose Testing Tools

```
from nose.tools import *

l = []
d = dict()

@raises(Exception)
def test_Exception1():
    '''this test should pass'''
    l.pop()

@raises(KeyError)
def test_Exception2():
    '''this test should pass'''
    d[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative, is to redirect output to stdout and use grep (adjust the number of lines, 15 in this example, to your liking):

```
nosetests tests.py 2>&1 | grep "ERROR" -A 15
```

Another alternative is to use  *--pdb-errors*  to stop on every error and open the debugger.

It's not what you asked, but it's what I ended up using.

Comment: There's a major difference between *logging* errors, and *stopping execution* on every error.

Comment: @Louis : I know, that's why I said it wasn't exactly what was asked. I edited my answer to include what I finally used (grep)